# Number of ways of selecting $N$ objects from a collection of $p, q, r$ different identical objects

Tags: logic, combinations

I came across a question in which I had to fill $N$ blank spaces with 3 different identical objects with at least one of each; that is $0<p$ identical objects, $0<q$ identical objects, and $0<r$ identical objects.

I have tried using combination and other logic but failed.

Comment: Since you have tried to use combinatorics , you should edit in your efforts too!

Comment: The question in the post is a generalized form. The original question was to fill 10 spaces with 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D and 3E(atleast one of each kind) so I chose 5 spaces out of 10 and filled them with each kind...now we have 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D and 2E then I got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to solving the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=N$ in natural numbers where each $x_i\geq1$. Or equivalently solve $x_1+x_2+x_3=N-3$ where each $x_i\geq0$ and $x_1\leq p,x_2\leq q,x_3\leq r$

This in turn is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{N-3}$ in
$(1+x+x^2+...+x^{p-1})(1+x+x^2+...+x^{q-1})(1+x+x^2+...+x^{r-1})$

=$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\frac{x^q-1}{x-1}\frac{x^r-1}{x-1}$

=$(1-x^p)(1-x^q)(1-x^r)(1-x)^{-3}$

this can be done by expanding $(1-x)^{-3}$ using the negative binomial theorem.

Comment: You have not included the upper bound for each $x_{i}$'s.

Comment: The $x_i$ 's are natural numbers , so obviously, none can't be greater than $N-3$ as then one of the others would have to be negative.

Comment: You are forgetting that there can be atmost $p$ of $x_{1}$ , $q$ of $x_{2}$ and $r$ of $x_{3}$

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to edit it.

Comment: Good. Now your answer is fine!

Answer (score 1):

this can be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle

- total number of configurations of N objects where either of the three types can be used is ${p + q + r \choose N}$
- total number of configurations of N object where either of only two types can be used is ${p + q \choose N} + {q + r \choose N} + {p + r \choose N}$
- total number of configurations of N object where only one type can be used is ${p \choose N} + {q \choose N} + {r \choose N}$

putting it all together gives
${p + q + r \choose N} - ({p + q \choose N} + {q + r \choose N} + {p + r \choose N}) + ({p \choose N} + {q \choose N} + {r \choose N})$